# Angular5 getting Error in HTTP GET request

Tags: php, mysql, angular

I am learning angular5 and I am following this tutorial for learning
https://angular.io/tutorial

I am PHP Developer using Linux OS and I am trying to fetch data from mysql database but I am getting below error

GET http://localhost:4200/api/getUsers 404 (Not Found)
[image]
can anyone help me to solve this ?

Please check code my three files

1.proxy-config.json

2.user.service.ts

3.app-routing.module.ts

---

```js
/*proxy-config.json*/
{
  "/api": {
  "target": "http://localhost:4200",
  "secure": false,
  "pathRewrite": {"^/api" : ""}
  }
}

/*user.service.ts*/
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { User } from './user';
import { USERS } from './mock-users';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
 
  private usersUrl = 'api/getUsers';  // URL to web api

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  /** GET users from the server */
  getUsers (): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http.get<User[]>(this.usersUrl)
      .pipe(
        tap(users => this.log(`fetched users`)),
        catchError(this.handleError('getUsers', []))
      );
  }

  /**
   * Handle Http operation that failed.
   * Let the app continue.
   * @param operation - name of the operation that failed
   * @param result - optional value to return as the observable result
   */
  private handleError<T> (operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

      // TODO: send the error to remote logging infrastructure
      console.error(error); // log to console instead

      // TODO: better job of transforming error for user consumption
      this.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);

      // Let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
      return of(result as T);
    };
  }

  /** Log a HeroService message with the MessageService */
  private log(message: string) {
    //this.messageService.add('HeroService: ' + message);
  }
  
}

/*app-routing.module.ts*/
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { UsersComponent } from './users/users.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'users',
    component: UsersComponent
  },    
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
     CommonModule
     ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  declarations: []
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Hi, can you please share your Angular code and your back end controller/data provider code?

Comment: I am using angular5 which code do you need ? @Deadpool

Comment: if you dont share any influyent  part of your code no one cant help you.

Comment: Because you posted a screenshot of a directory? How is that supposed to help anyone? Give a [mcve], per [ask].

Comment: Thanks for information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An angular app, by default runs on port 4200 unless you explicitly change it and you are making an AJAX request on the same port `http://localhost:4200/api/getUsers`.

I believe you intend to make an HTTP request on some other port where your server is running.

Comment: when I use this url "http://localhost/angular/my-app/api/getUsers/" I am getting erro r "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "

Comment: Then you need to add CORS related headers in the response headers from your backend. Just be sure that the API returns data either in a browser or Postman.

Comment: You can add `<?php header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` as per https://enable-cors.org/server_php.html to enable CORS. You may also configure your Apache server if you are using one.

Comment: I added following in my php file its working now.

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

Comment: Glad it helped :)